# Laravel issue with nesting subview in controller

Tags: php, html, laravel-5

I trying to nest the sub-view controller like

```
$rootElement = $this->getStyles();
        $styles = Styles::user()->where('parent_id',0)->get();
        return view("settings.style",compact("menu","rootElement"))
                  ->nest('styleModal','settings.add-style-modal',compact("rootElement"));
```

When display styleModal in view like

```
{{styleModal}}
```

It prints the html as text

[image]

Any thing which i am missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `{!! styleModal !!}` instead of `{{ styleModal }}`.

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#displaying-data).